# How to create Restful facade service in java?

Tags: java, rest, facade

I know to create Restful web service but I don't know how to implement restful facade in java.

I would appreciate if you share some links or examples of implementation.

Comment: Define what you mean by "restful facade".

Comment: per my understanding a service which is expose to the client but Its actual business process implementation in different service call. kind of distributed SOA. hope I clear to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't that specific, so hard to provide a targeted suggestion, but I've been using spring mvc to create restful webservices in java with a fair amount of success. Spring have an examples project, which it claims "demonstrates the capabilities of the Spring MVC web framework through small, simple examples":

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-mvc-showcase